# How to make MySQL can search every keywords from my input

Tags: mysql

First, I was search around here but no answer according to my need. Maybe wrong keyword I search :)

Example data from row `title` on my database.

1. `Stack Overflow`
2. `Stack Exchange`
3. `I love Stack Overflow`

Statement

```
SELECT title
FROM table
WHERE
(
    title LIKE '%keyword%'
 )
```

Question

What is the correct statement to display `1,2 & 3` if the keyword is `Stack Overflow`?

When I use `LIKE '%keyword%'` it's only return row number `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   title LIKE '%stack%'
        OR title LIKE '%overflow%'
```

If your table is `MyISAM`, you can create a `FULLTEXT` index on it and use

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   MATCH(title) AGAINST ('stack overflow' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to break every word out of your input, and use it in its own LIKE clause:

```
SELECT `title`
FROM `table`
WHERE (`title` LIKE '%Stack%' OR `title` LIKE '%Overflow%')
```

That said, I'm not sure why your original statement did not match the 3rd example you gave there.

Also, you may want to check out [fulltext indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html).  I've never had much success with it, but in theory, it is designed to do what you are trying to set up (assuming a few things, such as the MyISAM storage engine).